# FactoryGirl for Deep Nested_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I followed [NestedForm](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
 implemented that using  4.1.0 with ruby2.1.2 Used Rspec3.0 basic functional .

I used **after(create)** callback to create factory (has many relationship) **survey with questions**

```
after(:create) do |survey|
  survey.questions << FactoryGirl.build(:question, :survey => survey)
end
```

but now I want to create factory with survey,questions answers. How to do this ? help me...

**Model with relationship**

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy, inverse_of: :survey
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey, inverse_of: :questions
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy, inverse_of: :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:answers].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true,:limit => 2,:update_only => true
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question,inverse_of: :questions
end
```

Comment: please show us the models & their associations

Comment: @Anthony I updated the model with relationship.